# SSL HTTPS connection for WM 6 :untrusted Certificate

Tags: windows-mobile

Iam trying SSL connection in my C# application for WM6...Getting "message cant de displayed optional assemby missing" exception ......I am using code as follows

ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyPolicy();

public class MyPolicy : ICertificatePolicy
    {

```
    public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint sp, X509Certificate cert,   WebRequest req, int problem)
    {
        return true;

    }

}
```

But works fine in WM5.......Is anything to change....
Getting Exception for (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.Getresponse()

plz plz help me ....Suggest me wat can I do

Thanks in advance

Comment: thank for reply ...now i am able to figure out wat the exception is ie..WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
getting "Unable to read the transport network"

wat may goin wrong ..plz help..

Answer (score 0):

Install the resources file so you can at least get the exception text.

it is found at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE\Diagnostics\NetCFc35.Messages.EN.wm.cab